# Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I have been confused over when to use these two parsing methods.

After I echo my json_encoded data and retrieve it back via ajax, I often run into confusion about when I should use **JSON.stringify** and **JSON.parse**.

I get `[object,object]` in my *console.log* when parsed and a JavaScript object when stringified.

```
$.ajax({
url: "demo_test.txt",
success: function(data) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                     /* OR */
         console.log(JSON.parse(data))
        //this is what I am unsure about?
    }
});
```

Comment: To sum up the answers below: 1. They are the inverse of each other. 2. combined it helps to validate the data or turn human readable: `json.stringify(json.parse(data))`.

Answer (score 714, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` turns a JavaScript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string, eg:

```
var my_object = { key_1: "some text", key_2: true, key_3: 5 };

var object_as_string = JSON.stringify(my_object);  
// "{"key_1":"some text","key_2":true,"key_3":5}"  

typeof(object_as_string);  
// "string"
```

`JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into a JavaScript object, eg:

```
var object_as_string_as_object = JSON.parse(object_as_string);  
// {key_1: "some text", key_2: true, key_3: 5} 

typeof(object_as_string_as_object);  
// "object"
```

Comment: json.stringify(json.parse(data))?i saw this in code...so this is basically converting json data in to object and then again reconverting it to json data..

Comment: @MESSIAH — Yes. It's largely pointless, but might serve as a JSON validator.

Comment: Can also be used a simple object copy for object key value pairings.

Comment: @AnkurShah — Depends on what `obj` is.

Answer (score 61):

`JSON.parse()` is for "parsing" something that was received as JSON.
`JSON.stringify()` is to create a JSON string out of an object/array.

Comment: precision : it might not be an object.

Comment: True, could also be an array or anything Javascript recognizes as a certain type. Bottomline; it takes it and converts it to the appropriate JSON equivalent.

Comment: @dystroy — It has to be an object (noting that an arrays are objects).

Comment: @quentin `JSON.stringify(3)`

Comment: @dystroy — huh, didn't realize they'd expanded it to deal with JSON *fragments*. That's unintuitive.

Comment: @DenysSéguret `javascript:window.alert((3.14).toFixed())` I'd say that Numbers are objects too.

Answer (score 49):

They are the inverse of each other. `JSON.stringify()` serializes a JS object into a JSON string, whereas `JSON.parse()` will deserialize a JSON string into a JS object.

Answer (score 33):

They are the opposites of each other.

**JSON.stringify()**

JSON.stringify() serializes a JS object or value into a JSON string.

```
JSON.stringify({});                  // '{}'
JSON.stringify(true);                // 'true'
JSON.stringify('foo');               // '"foo"'
JSON.stringify([1, 'false', false]); // '[1,"false",false]'
JSON.stringify({ x: 5 });            // '{"x":5}'

JSON.stringify(new Date(2006, 0, 2, 15, 4, 5)) 
// '"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"'

JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 });
// '{"x":5,"y":6}' or '{"y":6,"x":5}'
JSON.stringify([new Number(1), new String('false'), new Boolean(false)]);
// '[1,"false",false]'
```

**JSON.parse()**

The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced.

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

Comment: A better name for `parse()` would be `objectify()` or `jsonify()`.

Comment: Why not JSON.toString() and JSON.toObject()? I would prefer these names (especially useful for new programmers that use intellisense).

Comment: you could have post https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify instead of copying

Comment: @nueverest `jsonify()` would be ambiguous and misleading, since `parse()` does *not* convert a `String` to a `JSON` type (which is what `jsonify()` would indicates), but `parse()` converts a *JSON-formatted* `String` to any of: `Object`, `Array`, `Number`, `String`, `Boolean` or `null`. People often confuse JSON "string representation" and `Object` (or `dict` in Python, etc.).

Answer (score 22):

Firstly, `JSON.stringify()` function converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string. `JSON.parse()` function converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an object. For more information about these two functions, please refer to the following links.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx

Secondly, the following sample will be helpful for you to understand these two functions.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        //define a json object
        var employee = { "name": "John Johnson", "street": "Oslo West 16", "phone": "555 1234567" };

        //use JSON.stringify to convert it to json string
        var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(employee);
        $("#result").append('<p>json string: ' + jsonstring + '</p>');

        //convert json string to json object using JSON.parse function
        var jsonobject = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
        var info = '<ul><li>Name:' + jsonobject.name + '</li><li>Street:' + jsonobject.street + '</li><li>Phone:' + jsonobject.phone + '</li></ul>';

        $("#result").append('<p>json object:</p>');
        $("#result").append(info);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var log = { "page": window.location.href, 
        "item": "item", 
        "action": "action" };

log = JSON.stringify(log);
console.log(log);
console.log(JSON.parse(log));
```

//The output will be:

//For 1st Console is a String Like:

```
'{ "page": window.location.href,"item": "item","action": "action" }'
```

//For 2nd Console is a Object Like:

```
Object {
page   : window.location.href,  
item   : "item",
action : "action" }
```

Answer (score 11):

`JSON.stringify()` Converts an object into a string.

`JSON.parse()` Converts a JSON string into an object.

Comment: "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." Antoine de Saint-Exupery

Answer (score 9):

The real confusion here is not about parse vs stringify, it's about the data type of the `data` parameter of the success callback.

`data` can be either the raw response, i.e a string, or it can be an JavaScript object, as per the documentation:

> success
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A
>   function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified;<..>

And the dataType defaults to a setting of 'intelligent guess'

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will **try to infer** it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Comment: This is a very useful addition, because it helps understand what the confusion is all about!

Answer (score 8):

They are the complete opposite of each other.

[**`JSON.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is used for ***parsing*** data that was received as **JSON**; *it **deserializes** a **JSON string** into a **JavaScript object***.

[**`JSON.stringify()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on the other hand is used to create a **JSON string** out of an **object** or **array**; *it **serializes** a **JavaScript object** into a **JSON string***.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's been mentioned, but one of the uses of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)) is to create a clone of the original object.

This is handy when you want to mess with some data without affecting the original object.  Probably not the cleanest / fastest way but certainly the simplest for objects that aren't massively complex.

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.stringify(obj [, replacer [, space]])` - Takes any serializable object and returns the JSON representation as a string.

`JSON.parse(string)` - Takes a well formed JSON string and returns the corresponding JavaScript object.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript Object <-> JSON String

---

```
JSON.stringify() <-> JSON.parse()
```

---

JSON.stringify(obj) - Takes any serializable object and returns the JSON representation as a string.

```
JSON.stringify() -> Object To String.
```

JSON.parse(string) - Takes a well formed JSON string and returns the corresponding JavaScript object.

```
JSON.parse() -> String To Object.
```

**Explanation:** 
   JSON.stringify(obj [, replacer [, space]]);

Replacer/Space - optional or takes integer value or you can call interger type return function.

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'number' && !isFinite(value)) {
        return String(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

- Replacer Just Use for replace non finite no with null.
- Space use for indenting Json String by space

Answer (score 4):

They are opposing each other.
`JSON.Stringify()` converts JSON to string and `JSON.Parse()` parses a string into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

JSON : It is mainly used to exchange data to/from the server. Before sending 
     the JSON object to the server, it has to be a string.

```
JSON.stringify() //Converts the JSON object into the string representation.
var jsonData={"Name":"ABC","Dept":"Software"};// It is a JSON object
var jsonString=JSON.stringify(jsonData);// It is a string representation of the object
// jsonString === '{"Name":"ABC","Dept":"Software"}'; is true
```

It also converts the Javascript array into string

```
var arrayObject=["ABC","Software"];// It is array object
var arrString=JSON.stringify(array);// It is string representation of the array (object)
// arrString === '["ABC","Software"]'; is true
```

When we received the JSON data from the server, the data would be the string format.Hence we convert the string into JSON object.

```
JSON.parse() //To convert the string into JSON object.
var data='{ "name":"ABC", "Dept":"Software"}'// it is a string (even though it looks like an object)
var JsonData= JSON.parse(data);// It is a JSON Object representation of the string.
// JsonData === { "name":"ABC", "Dept":"Software"}; is true
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` is used to convert String to Object.
`JSON.stringify()` is used to convert Object to String.

You can refer this too...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_get_json(){

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "JSON/mylist.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json",true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
           /*  var return_data = hr.responseText; */

           var data=JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
           var status=document.getElementById("status");
           status.innerHTML = "";
           /* status.innerHTML=data.u1.country;  */
           for(var obj in data)
               {
               status.innerHTML+=data[obj].uname+" is in "+data[obj].country+"<br/>";
               }

        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    status.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON.parse()** takes a JSON string and transforms it into a JavaScript object.

**JSON.stringify()** takes a JavaScript object and transforms it into a JSON string.

```
const myObj = {
      name: 'bipon',
      age: 25,
      favoriteFood: 'fish curry'
};

 const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);

console.log(myObjStr);
// "{"name":"bipon","age":26,"favoriteFood":"fish curry"}"

console.log(JSON.parse(myObjStr));
 // Object {name:"bipon",age:26,favoriteFood:"fish curry"}
```

And although the methods are usually used on objects, they can also be used on arrays:

```
const myArr = ['simon', 'gomez', 'john'];

const myArrStr = JSON.stringify(myArr);

console.log(myArrStr);
// "["simon","gomez","john"]"

console.log(JSON.parse(myArrStr));
// ["simon","gomez","john"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse a string (written in JSON format) and return a JavaScript object

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}');
```

Stringify a JavaScript object:

```
var obj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

When a client (for example a browser sends data to or gets data from) it needs to send a string. You can't send data as
JavaScript object.

When a JavaSript data comes to the client as a string, then we need to convert back the string to an object so we can process
in the client-side in a convenient way.