# how do you pass text as a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i have an element that I want to convey 2 or more pieces of data with a single click....

```
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',1]" >week 1</a>
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',2]" >week 2</a>
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',3]" >week 3</a>
...and so forth.

$( '.quickie' ).click( function() {
        var dataArray = JSON.stringify( $( this ).attr( 'data' ) );
        var month = dataArray[0];
        var week = dataArray[1];
});
```

This seems to treat the entire string as an array with each character being its own element.??
I thought "JSON.stringify()" would solve this, but it doesn't.

Help please.either straight javascript, or jquery would do.

Comment: It's `JSON.parse()`. Here, you are converting a String to... a String.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse)

Answer (score 4):

**[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** converts an object to a JSON string.

You have a JSON string in the `data` attribute that you want to *parse* as a JavaScript object.

Use **[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse( $( this ).attr( 'data' ) );
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON datavar 

dataArray = JSON.parse( $( this ).attr( 'data' ) );

Answer (score 3):

`html` at

```
data="['jan',1]"
```

returns

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

try substituting

```
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",1]'>week 1</a>
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",2]'>week 2</a>
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",3]'>week 3</a>
```

for

```
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',1]" >week 1</a>
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',2]" >week 2</a>
<a class="quickie" data="['jan',3]" >week 3</a>
```

additionally, appear to be syntax error at close of `.click()` handler; try substituting

```
});
```

for

```
)};
```

utilizing `JSON.parse` to parse string at `.data()` , instead of `JSON.stringify` , which returns string representation of object , not object parsed from string at `data-*` attribute

---

```js
$(".quickie").click( function() {
        var dataArray = JSON.parse($( this ).attr("data"));
        var month = dataArray[0];
        var week = dataArray[1];
        console.log(dataArray, month, week);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",1]'>week 1</a>
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",2]'>week 2</a>
<a class="quickie" data='["jan",3]'>week 3</a>
```

Comment: I'll try swapping the quotes, but the closing }); was my fault in typin gthe question, it is not that way in the code... thx

Answer (score 0):

Excellent - the solution was a combination of two suggestions...

## 1 - had to change my "quoting structure" - it's a little frustrating, but oh well

## 2 - the JSON.parse then works with the updated quotes

thank you all.