# get value from JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json

i want to get simple one value from a json data row.

```
// json: {"id":1,"name":"test1","price":"$1"} 
var id = JSON.stringify(row).id;
```

but it doesnt work. Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: You want JSON.parse() not stringify

Comment: Well, `.stringify()` creates a string, so...

Comment: You need to use JSON.parse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse

Comment: thanks Hunan, in my case row.id works !

Answer (score 2):

try this.

JSON.stringify(row, ["id"])