# request data to ajax call is converting to js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is My ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8081/organizations/',
    data: JSON.stringify({"name":"karthik"}),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType :'json',
    processData : true,

    success: (function(response){ alert("response "+response);}),
    error: (function(err){ console.log(err); }) 
});
```

In the api, when i tried to print request.data, why i am getting like this `{u'{"name":"karthik"}': [u'']}`

Comment: Read this question should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line

```
success: (function(response){ alert("response "+response);}),
```

by newone

```
success: (function(response){ alert(JSON.stringify(response));}),
```

In your code and then try it will work.