# How to extract inner string from the array string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string, containing an array, containing a string:

```
   '["sgrdalal21"]'
```

How can I extract the inner string?

Comment: Simple read its first index `var str = ["sgrdalal21"][0]`

Comment: Thanx @Satpal, but its giving me only this character `[`

Comment: Then `["sgrdalal21"]` is a string not an array. Test once `JSON.parse('["sgrdalal21"]')[0]`

Comment: Yehh, It was string ,Thanx @Satpal. But this Question is not same as you marked Bro!

Comment: Ok Satpal i have edit it, open it so others can take advantage of solution

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that such piece of data is the result of some double encoding. If so, and whenever possible, it'd be better to just fix the code that generates the data rather than adding a workaround on top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `'["sgrdalal21"]'` as string, [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be used to construct the JavaScript value or object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('["sgrdalal21"]');
var str = obj[0]; //Use index to access the element
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a JSON string:

```
var json = '["sgrdalal21"]';
```

You have to parse it as JSON to have an ordinary array.
Then you can access the string in the array:

```
var array, string;
try {
  array = JSON.parse(json);
  string = array[0];
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

Remember that whenever you parse JSON strings which you are not sure that are valid (which is usually the case) then you will always have to wrap the `JSON.parse()` call inside a `try/catch` block or otherwise your app will crash on invalid JSON. I noticed that people rarely handle `JSON.parse()` errors in the examples and then people are surprised that their servers are crashing and don't know why. It's because `JSON.parse()` throws exceptions on bad input and has to be used with `try/catch` to avoid crashing the entire app:

```
var array;
try {
  array = JSON.parse(json);
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

You can also use [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) for that:

```
var array = tryjson.parse(json);
```

that will do that for you automatically. Now you can use:

```
var string = array && array[0];
```

and here the `string` variable will be `undefined` if the JSON was invalid or the array did not contain any elements, or will be equal to the inner string, just like in that first example with `try/catch` above.