# Read Json inside javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have below Json output and i am trying to read sample_rate field. Before reading i am checking if any data exists

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "sample_rate": 5000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to do this using below code but getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

```
function(error, response, body){
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log("inside t1");
                    let tsales = JSON.parse(body);
                    var tsales2 = JSON.stringify(tsales);
                     console.log(tsales2);
                    console.log("inside t2");
                    if (tsales2.response.hasOwnProperty("docs")) {
                        console.log("inside t3");
                        let reply = `${responseText} ${tsales2.response["docs"][0]["sample_rate"]}`;
                        sendTextMessage(sender, reply);
                    } else {
                        let tsales = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log("inside t4");
                        sendTextMessage(sender,
                            `No sales available for ${parameters["brand"]}`);
                    }
```

Comment: Replace `if (tsales2.response.hasOwnProperty("docs")) {` with `if (tsales2.response.docs) {`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts the data to a string instead of an object.  So if you, in fact, have an object with your `JSON.parse`, you should just work with that - `tsales.response.hasOwnProperty("docs");`

Comment: using JSON.stringify is good for your `console.log` output - but use the object for accessing values within your code.

Comment: And you should not have to JSON.parse again in that last conditional block.
And use that same variable for `let reply = \`${responseText} ${tsales.response["docs"][0]["sample_rate"]}\`;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
if (tsales.response.docs)
```

OR

```
if (tsales.response.hasOwnProperty("docs"))
```

Referring to [Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse) 
`JSON.parse()` turns a string of `JSON text` into a Javascript `object` which you can use to reference your `hasOwnProperty` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Why `JSON.parse(body)` and then `JSON.stringify(tsales) ?`. If you want to `parse` the JSON Object then no need to do `JSON.stringify(tsales)`.
- `JSON.stringify(tsales)` will convert the `JSON Object` into `JSON String` then this statement `tsales2.response.hasOwnProperty("docs")` will return false as `tsales2` is no more a `JSON Object`.
- > TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

  means that `tsales2.response` is not exist or we can say not defined as you converted it into `JSON String`.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(tsales)`  will convert the `tsales JSON object` into `JSON string object,` And that will not have the  `hasOwnProperty method` in string object that's why it's return false and execute the else block, To Solve the issue no need to stringify the tsales like below code

```
function(error, response, body){
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("inside t1");
    let tsales = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(tsales);
    console.log("inside t2");
    if (tsales.response.hasOwnProperty("docs")) {
      console.log("inside t3");
      let reply = `${responseText} ${tsales.response["docs"][0]["sample_rate"]}`;
      sendTextMessage(sender, reply);
    } else {
      let tsales = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("inside t4");
      sendTextMessage(sender,
        `No sales available for ${parameters["brand"]}`);
    }
  }
}
```