# axios gives me JSON object, but can't parse to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, aurelia, axios

I've been trying to figure this out, and don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.  I'm also new to Aurelia, Typescript, and Axios.

The backend gives me a JSON array of objects that I want to parse into Javascript Objects. Cool. For my fake data I'm using JSONplaceholder. When I parse, what is returned is [object Object] (see link to image at bottom).  What am I doing incorrectly?  Eventually I'd like to pull specific data out, like info.name, and display the name.

test.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
const apiURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

declare var $: any;


export class Test {
    info: string;
    infoX: string;
    public constructor () {
      axios.get(apiURL)
        .then(response => {
          this.info = JSON.stringify(response.data)
          this.infoX = JSON.parse(this.info);
          console.log(this.info);
          console.log(this.infoX);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

test.html

```
<template>
  <pre style="margin-top: 200px">${info}</pre>
  <pre style="margin-top: 200px">${infoX}</pre>
</template>
```

[screenshot of what the console log and view displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44QjQ.jpg)

Comment: No, the back-end gives you a JSON string - so get rid of JSON.stringify in your response handler.  Now, say you have an array of objects in javascript and you try to set it as the html of some div - you will get `[[Object object],[Object object]...]`.  You need to iterate the array pull out the various properties from the objects and display them.

Comment: Your problem is not in parsing, but in printing. `${infoX}` converts the array to a string which is not the same as `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @James thanks for the reply. Can you clarify something for me?  If the backend gives me a string, does the array of objects have to be in quotes?

Comment: Usually the backend function you use to turn a native object or array into JSON takes care of all the quotes, it looks like you're sending/receiving the JSON just fine though.

Comment: @James, thanks for the help and clarification.  Pointed me in the right direction. The key was iterate like you mentioned. And understanding JSON.parse and JSON.stringify better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link helped clear up some confusion I was having: [simple explanation of JSON.parse and JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse)

Then listening to Jame's advice in the comments I iterated over the array, and returned the data from server.

test.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
const apiURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

export class Data {
    infos: string;
    public constructor () {
      axios.get(apiURL)
        .then(response => {
          this.infos = response.data;
          console.log(this.infos);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

test.html

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li repeat.for="info of infos">
          Name: ${info.name}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```