# Convert JSON string to object and display as HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have a `dropdown select option` with `onchange event` which will send selected value via `AJAX` to my controller and then query data based on the selected value from MySQL database and return it as `JSON` object to my blade.

My problem is the `JSON` data from mysql database currently in string as a single row. How to convert it back into normal `JSON` object and display each value based on the column name as `HTML` table in a new window.

**Process that suppose to be like this**

1. Select date from the dropdown option.
2. Get data from database based on date selected.
3. Convert JSON string to object and return it to the blade.
4. Display the data as HTML table on new window.

**Controller Code for inserting JSON to MySQL database**

```
$sqlquery = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
                ->table('Stocks')
                ->join('StockTransactions', 'Stocks.Id', '=', 'StockTransactions.StockId')
                ->select(
                   'TransactionDate',
                   'DocumentCode',
                   'DocType',
                   'StockName',
                   DB::raw("FORMAT(SUM(UOMQty), 'N') AS TotalUOMQty"),
                   DB::raw("FORMAT(SUM(UOMPrice), 'N') AS TotalUOMPrice"),
                   DB::raw("FORMAT(CurrentBalance, 'N') AS CurrentBalance"),
                   DB::raw("FORMAT(((SUM(UOMPrice) / SUM(UOMQty)) * CurrentBalance), 'N') AS Total")
                    )
                ->where([
                    ['UOMQty', '>', '0'],
                    ['DocumentCode', 'NOT LIKE', 'SA%'],
                    ['DocumentCode', 'NOT LIKE', 'SIN%']
                ])
                ->WhereBetween('TransactionDate', ['01-01-2000', $dateto])
                ->groupBy('StockName', 'TransactionDate', 'CurrentBalance', 'DocumentCode', 'DocType')
                ->orderBy('TransactionDate', 'ASC')
                ->get();

$array = json_decode(json_encode($sqlquery), true);
$json  = json_encode($array);

 DB::connection('mysql')
     ->table('records')
     ->insert(['record' => $json, 'date_from' => "2000-01-01", 'date_to' => "$dateto", 'date_inquiry' => "$getCurrentDateTimeTo"]);
```

**Controllor Code for getting JSON from MySQL database**

```
public function getmysqldata(Request $request)
{
  $request_data = $request->all();
  $dateInquiry = $request_data['dateInquiry'];

  $result = DB::connection('mysql')
                ->table('records')
                ->where([
                  'date_inquiry' => "$dateInquiry"
                ]) 
                ->get();

  return response()->json($result);
}
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
Record Available :                             
<select name="recordavailable" id="recordavailable">
  @if(!empty($inquiry_date))
    <option value="">Please select records</option> 
    @foreach ($inquiry_date as $date_inquiry)
      <option value="{{ $date_inquiry->date_inquiry}}">{{ $date_inquiry->date_inquiry}}</option>
    @endforeach  
  @else 
    option value="">No records</option>                
  @endif                                  
</select>
```

**Scripts**

```
$(document).on("change", 'select#recordavailable', function(e) 
{
   var dateInquiry = $(this).val();
   $.ajax
   ({
      type: "GET",               
      data: 'dateInquiry='+dateInquiry,               
      url: 'getmysqldata',
      dataType: 'JSON',                
      success: function(data) 
      { 
         var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 

         var winPrint = window.open('',"",'PopUp'+randomnumber+', "scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1"');

         winPrint.document.write('<title>Display Record of '+dateInquiry+'</title><style>table{ border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;'+
                            'width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ddd;}table, td, th{border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;padding: 5px;}#stockname {text-align: left;}'+
                            'h3 {text-align:center;}#qty, #cost, #balance, #total {text-align: right;}</style><h3>'+dateInquiry+'</h3>'); 

         winPrint.document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
      } 
   });            
});
```

**Console**

[image: console]

**Output**

[image: Output]

**The Output I want it to be**

[image: expectedoutput]

Comment: `winPrint.document.write(JSON.stringify(data));` is literally just going to dump the JSON string to the browser. The JSON object is `data` is still a JSON object weather it is one line or many. The server responding with JSON will compress it to one line to save bandwidth. You need to parse the JSON to a table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785623/10634638

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the record column in records table as array, which will cast it in proper json in output.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: I don't use model